# Texture not working on object

Tags: unity, 3d, textures, uv-mapping

I have a project that I'm having a bit of trouble with. Let me try and explain. In short, I'm trying to apply a texture to an object, but instead it is a solid color.

I built a building in "Autodesk 123d design", and exported it as stl. Then I used an online converter to convert it to obj, then added that to the unity scene. I created a material with a texture and tried to apply it to the object, but it was a solid color.

I think the UVs on the object might be messed up. I tried some things in blender, but had no luck. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is the 3D model I'm working with: http://www.123dapp.com/123D_Design/Conisbrough-Castle-Keep/4578568

Comment: What exactly did you try in Blender?

Comment: @RyanHenry I looked at a few YouTube tutorials regarding UV maps, but as I said, I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STL file is a poor format for exporting 3D art, it only support 3D geometry. from wikipedia

> STL files describe only the surface geometry of a three-dimensional
>   object without any representation of color, texture or other common
>   CAD model attributes. The STL format specifies both ASCII and binary
>   representations. Binary files are more common, since they are more
>   compact.[6]

Try other richer formats such as `Fbx` or at least `Obj` when exporting from your 3D modelling program. I assume STL is only support for legacy reasons.

Comment: 123D design only supports `STL` and `SAT/STEP` for export options. They do have their own format `.123dx`. Would any of those work better? If not, is there a way I can add the missing components back into the `obj` file?

Comment: @FelisPhasma you need to add UV mapping in another application, from their page 123design is most suitable for 3d printers where UV is not needed. Try blender. it's a good free 3d modeling tool.

Comment: I will probably use blender in the future, but I used 123d design this time because it was more simple. But now that I have used 123d design, how can I add the UVs back in?

Comment: you have to import it to blender, assign UV maps either manually or using one of the UV map generators (cubic, spherical etc).